# Why do ASP.NET MVC Controller classes need to be public?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I make a change to the access modifier of a controller class it results in an error. If I make the accessibility of an action method non-public then it also results in an error (specifically a *page not found* error). Why is this the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default if you not specify any access modifier for a class then it will default to `internal` in C#. Only code in the same assembly can access a class that is `internal`. So if your controller is `internal`, the code that creates a controller instance upon receiving a request would have to be in your assembly.

But controller creation code is present in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly and by default `DefaultControllerFactory` is responsible for creating controllers. If your code is present in, for example, the MvcApplication1 assembly then DefaultControllerFActory can not find your controller classes without the public access modifier so it is not able to instantiate them.

If you want to build a tightly coupled ASP.NET MVC application (which it is not it designed for) then theoretically you could do it following way.

1. Get the MVC source code if available.
2. Then build your code in same assembly.

Comment: but when i make controller as internal then it should be generate compile time error. By default class has internal access modifier that's why code does not return compilation error. My question is that if i make controller as internal then build successful but when i make controller as protected internal then it return a compilation error.

Comment: Compiler does not know that you are compile for MVC or another C# application. It just compile as follow the rules. Rules says that you can declare internal class at root level (inside namespace) but you can not create protected internal class at root level but you can create nested class with proctected internal.

Comment: For completion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: I wonder if we can fix this using `assembly:InternalsVisibleTo()`