# class access modifier in C#

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

I know it's a very basic questions but I'm just a newbie in C#. I know the default access modifier for class in C# is "internal" which means available in the same assembly. But let's say I have two public(more accessibility) class Employee and Departments in models, so they don't need to reference each other, fair enough. But I also a DepartmentController and EmployeeController in the controllers, and I need to reference class Employee and Departments, but aren't DepartmentController, EmployeeController Employee and Departments in the same assembly which is the project name?

This is the picture of the program:
[image]

Comment: I think you may be mixing up [namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx) with [Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx).

Comment: If you put them in the same assembly, then they are.

Comment: @cubrr I added a program picture to my post.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I added a program picture to my post.

Comment: I believe what he's getting at is that making his controllers internal is breaking his solution.  The reason for which is explained here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457287/why-does-the-asp-net-mvc-controller-class-need-to-be-public

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference those classes because they aren't in the same namespace (MVCDemo. Controller!= MVCDemo. Models). If you import those classes to the scope of another project by importing their assembly, you are going to be able to see only the public classes, not the internals. I highly recommend that you try to move the models to a Class Library Project and play with their access modifiers to understand their scope implication better (Like trying to import an internal class withing another assembly).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution has a single project, and there's a single assembly for your project.

The reason why the you need public access modifiers on your controllers is explained here...

[Why does the ASP.NET MVC Controller class need to be public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457287/why-does-the-asp-net-mvc-controller-class-need-to-be-public)

Basically the MVC framework you're referencing needs access to the controllers in order for them to be used by the framework, if they're internal the MVC framework would not be able to access your controllers.

Whilst there's a single project in your solution, you're referencing many other assemblies. Anything within a project that needs to be accessed by another assembly, be it an assembly created from one of your projects or an assembly you're referencing, needs to have the Public access modifier.